# Гардероб и раздевалка

Tags: этимология, лексика, значение-слов

Какая разница между гардеробом и раздевалкой? Как произошли эти слова?

Увидел объявление:  "Гардероб не охраняется, ответственность не несем".

Answer (score 3):

Слово "гардероб" заимствовано из фр. языка в начале 18 века (в форме "гардероба"), причем  оно могло обозначать как "набор одежды", так и "шкаф для одежды". Например, в "Архиве Куракина" (1711 год): гардероба своя: 12 башмаков пар и т.д.

Почему раздевалка

Чтобы одеться, надо сначала раздеться, поэтому прежде всего "раздевалка" (приходится выбирать одно из двух). Аналогичный пример - включатель/выключатель. Решено было, что что выключатель важнее.

Comment: С "раздевалкой" согласна. Человек приходит изначально одетый, а там уже раздевается и позже одевается. Кстати, и переодевается, например, на физкультуру. 
   Таких слов много. Та же отвертка. Но ей не только отворачивают, но и вкручивают.

Answer (score 0):

Одеваются  люди  дома,  а  раздеваются  в  общественных  местах.  Поэтому  и  раздевалка.  Дома  раздевалок  не  устраивают.  Зато  дома  есть  платяной  шкаф.  Или  гардероб,  кому  как  нравится.  В  гардеробе  одежда  висит  на  плечиках,  и  в  раздевалке  тоже  висит.  Иногда  и  на  плечиках.  Потому  и  гардероб.

Comment: А Вы уверены, что раздеваются только в общественных места?
Вообще то, мне показалось смешным сочетание слов "гардероб, что означает хранение, сохранность сданной одежды и "ответственность не несем" в объявлении.
Гардероб- хранение одежды- можно устраивать кому как захочется, в т.ч. и на плечиках.

Comment: Ну,  если  смысл  слова  "раздеваются"  не  доводить  до  абсурда,  то  раздеваются  в  гардеробах  и  раздевалках  в  местах  общественных.  Хотя  не  исключено,  что  где-нибудь  и  вешалку  в  домашней  прихожей  могут  назвать  раздевалкой.  А  ответственность  за  одежду  должна  быть  независимо  от  названия,  будь  то  гардероб,  раздевалка  или  вешалка  в  вестибюле.  А  то,  если  спуститься  к  истокам  слова  гардероб,  обнаружится  сундук,  куда  одежду  не  сдавали,  а  просто  хранили.